# Bancha basic version with Ext JS - not showing data in grid

Tags: cakephp, extjs, bancha

I am using Bancha basic version for my site. I want to show data from emplyees table to grid using Ext JS.

Following is the code for controller:

```
class EmployeesController extends AppController { 
    /** 
    * @banchaRemotable 
    */ 
    public function getData(){
        return $this->Employee->find('all');
    }
}
```

Following is my JavaScript file:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'BanchaExample',

launch: function() {

    /**
     * Example 1
     * Create a grid panel which provides full CRUD support
     */ 

    Bancha.getStub('Employee').index(function(result){
        Ext.define('Employee', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [ 'id', 'name' ]
        });
        var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Employee',
            data: result.data
            });
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            model: 'Employee',
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            title: 'Application Users',
            //scaffold: 'MyApp.model.User'
            columns: [
                {
                    header: 'id',
                    width: 100,
                    ryinsortable: false,
                    hideable: false,
                    dataIndex: 'id'
                },
                {
                    header: 'name',
                    width: 150,
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }
            ]
        });
    });      
}
});
```

It gives me following response in my console:

> [{"type":"rpc","tid":1,"action":"Employee","method":"read","result":{"success":true,"data":[{"Employee":{"id":"1","name":"test"}},{"Employee":{"id":"2","name":"tese"}}],"message":"Expected the response to be multiple Employee records, but some records were missing data, so did not convert data into Ext JS/Sencha Touch structure."}}]

Only grid with header is displayed. Data is not displayed.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Bancha, but may be this will help.
I don't see any grid connection with store. Also store need some config(reader) to parse your result. 'data' is normally used for inline static data.

```
   Ext.define('Employee', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'id',
        mapping : 'Employee.id'
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        mapping : 'Employee.name'
    } ]
    });
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'Employee',
    proxy : {
        url : 'SPECIFY URL TO YOUR SERVICE',
        type : 'ajax',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'result.data'
        }

    }
});

also add store to grid and you can remove model in grid

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store : myStore,
            ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bancha Basic does not automatically transform records from the CakePHP structure to Ext JS. For what you want to do you need to use Bancha Pro.

If you want to use Bancha Basic you need to return a correct Ext JS data array.